# Adding brand logo works in product view but not in search result

Tags: magento-1.7

I've added the brand logo in the product view phtml file like this:

```
<div>
<?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand');
echo '<img src="media/catalog/brand/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.png" alt="'.$brand.'">' ?>
</div>
```

It returns the correct url, for example for "acme" brand the resulting url is:

```
media/catalog/brand/acme.png
```

I tried to add the same code in the catalog/product/list.phtml file, but the link is broken and the generate url is:

```
media/catalog/brand/.png
```

So it seems like the brand attribute is not extracted. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the value for 'Use in product listing' to 'Yes' on the attribute 'brand'.

Comment: Thank you!! How could I have missed that???